# mathjax broken for prime + no-braces superscript + subscript

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mathjax

It seems that terms like $q'^a_b$ stopped rendering correctly, since their superscript/subscript are not surrounded by braces (e.g., $q'^{a}_b$ should work). The error shown in preview is `Missing open brace for superscript`.

See, for instance,
[CS.SE/2984](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2984/)

Comment: Must be [this update](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23019/mathjax-editing-updates-beta)

Comment: Your example of `q^a_b` seems ok. The question is a special case: primes are treated as superscripts, so you need braces to identify where the subscript belongs (to the prime or to the base).

Comment: @Gilles, it is not the update you indicate, which doesn't alter the expressions that MathJax will display.  It was actually the update to MathJax v2.1 back in October of 2012 that caused those expressions to fail to parse.

Comment: In LaTeX ' is a shortcut for ^{\prime}. So you want $q^{\prime a}_b$.

Comment: Please include a screenshot so the post makes sense in the future!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Peter points out in the comments, the issue in the linked post is about combining primes with carets (`^`).  The expression `q^'_0` is invalid LaTeX (it produces an error message even in LaTeX).  Version 2.0 incorrectly processed this expression, but that was fixed in version 2.1, which was released back in October of 2012 (a few months after the post you cite was written).  So the expressions have not parsed correctly for several years.  The correct form should be `q'_0` not `q^'_0`.  Note that `q^a_b` is fine, but `q^'_0` is not because of the special way that TeX treats the prime.